# Combining multiple data sets in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I am a complete beginner in R/ programming language. Right now I am trying to process hundreds of comma separated data files using R. For time series analyses, I need to concatenate the data sets sequentially. Unfortunately, the data files do not have a designated column with time stamp and have some header lines. For that, I am parsing the file creation time from the second line of the data file and adding timesteps based on the sampling frequency which can be found in the third line of the data file. Also, the sampling frequency will vary from files to files that can be identified from the regex patterns in filename. The first three header lines look like this:

```
SPU1 Monitor Data File
SPU Data Filename = 06Aug2021 ,07 -08 -28,s1c1h17.txt
Sample Frequency = 1
```

Or

```
SPU1 Traffic Data File
SPU Data Filename = 05Aug2021 ,02 -48 -14,s1c1p2311.txt
Sample Frequency = 20
```

I have tried the for loop as well as the lapply. When I am trying the for loop, the script only run once. When I am trying the lapply, I am getting the following message. What am I doing wrong?

```
[Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In n.readLines(paste(filenames\[i\], sep = ","), header = FALSE, n = 1,  :
  file doesn't exist
2: In n.readLines(paste(filenames\[i\], sep = ",|\\s|-"), header = FALSE,  :
  file doesn't exist
Called from: file(file, "rt")][1]
```

Here is the code I am trying:

```
setwd("C:/Users/rottweiller/Desktop/Practicing R")

filenames <- list.files(path="C:/Users/rottweiller/Desktop/Practicing R", pattern="c1h|c1p", full.names=FALSE)

library(reader)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)

AddTS <- function(filenames){
        #frq1 <- parse_number(n.readLines(paste(filenames[i], sep = ","), header = FALSE, n = 1, skip = 2))
        frq1 <- as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", n.readLines(paste(filenames[i], sep = ","), header = FALSE, n = 1, skip = 2)))
        TL1 <- n.readLines(paste(filenames[i], sep = ",|\\s|-"), header = FALSE, n = 1, skip = 1)
        SUTC1 <- lubridate::parse_date_time(gsub("\\s-|\\s", "",
                stringr::str_extract(TL1, "[SPU Data Filename = ]?\\d{2}\\D{3}\\d{4}\\s\\,\\d{2}\\s-\\d{2}\\s-\\d{2}")), orders = "dmYHMS")
  C1 <- as.data.frame(read.delim(filenames[i], header = FALSE, sep = ",", skip = 79))
  C1[] <- lapply(C1, function(j) if(is.numeric(j)) ifelse(is.infinite(j), 0, j) else j)
  TS1 <- SUTC1 + (1/frq1)*seq_len(nrow(C1))
  Card1 <- cbind(TS1, C1)
}

combined <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(filenames, AddTS))
```

**Or**

```
[for(i in 1:length(filenames)){
    frq1 <- parse_number(n.readLines(paste(filenames\[i\], sep = ","), header = FALSE, n = 1, skip = 2), trim_ws = TRUE)
    TL1 <- n.readLines(paste(filenames\[i\], sep = ",|\\s|-"), header = FALSE, n = 1, skip = 1)
    SUTC1 <- lubridate::parse_date_time(gsub("\\s-|\\s", "",
                                             stringr::str_extract(TL1, "\[SPU Data Filename = \]?\\d{2}\\D{3}\\d{4}\\s\\,\\d{2}\\s-\\d{2}\\s-\\d{2}")),
                                        orders = "dmYHMS")
    C1 <- as.data.frame(read.delim(filenames\[i\], header = FALSE, sep = ",", skip = 79))
    C1\[\] <- lapply(C1, function(j) if(is.numeric(j)) ifelse(is.infinite(j), 0, j) else j)
    TS1 <- SUTC1 + (1/frq1)*seq_len(nrow(C1))
    Card1 <- cbind(TS1, C1)
}][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good starting step that you already know about regular expressions and recent R libraries.

You could do something like this:

```r
purrr::map_dfr(filenames, function(f) {
  lines <- readLines(file(f))
  
  frq <- lines[3] %>%
    str_replace(".*?(\\d*)$", "\\1") %>%
    as.integer()
  frq
  
  SUTC <- lines[2] %>%
    stringr::str_extract("[SPU Data Filename = ]?\\d{2}\\D{3}\\d{4}\\s\\,\\d{2}\\s-\\d{2}\\s-\\d{2}") %>%
    lubridate::parse_date_time(orders = "dmYHMS")
  SUTC
  
  C <- lines[(which(lines == "end of text") + 2):length(lines)] %>%
    textConnection() %>%
    read.delim(header = FALSE, sep = ",") %>%
    mutate(across(.fns = ~ if_else(. == Inf, 0, .)))
  C
  
  TS <- SUTC + seq_len(nrow(C)) / frq
  
  bind_cols(file = f, TS = TS, C)
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have added some context. I have eight different equipment setups. Each of these setups have 27 sensors. These 216 sensors are connected through 4 different DAQ modules. Each module hosts 63 channels. The "c1" part in the filename "06Aug2021 ,07 -08 -28,s1c1h17.txt" is designated to module 1 or Card 1. Similarly, TS1 stands for the initial timestamp (time at which the file was created) from Card 1. Lines 5 through 79 list all the sensor names and excitation voltage channels. The actual comma separated data starts from line 80.

Comment: Could you upload one file as reference? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386997/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-stack-overflow

Comment: Here is a google drive link to an actual data file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xVGPyIPFHnZrFFpV1f3UkZvau9MUxd-2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Your code seems to be working.

Though as a beginner, I would like to learn a bit more about regex. In the "str_replace(".*?(\\d*)$", "\\1")" part, what does the "\\1" mean? What is the actual replacement?

Comment: That regexp means "take the last characters of the string if they are digits".